# WPF8 Messagebox

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, messagebox

I'm trying to implement this code:

```
 Dim result As MessageBoxResult = _
 MessageBox.Show("Would you like to see the simple version?", _
 "MessageBox Example", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel)

 If (result = MessageBoxResult.OK) Then
     MessageBox.Show("No caption, one button.")
 End If
```

But getting an error: Type 'MessageBoxResult' is not defined
Why is happening?

I'm using: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 Version 12.0.30501.00 Update 2 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.51641

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If System.Windows didn't resolve then you had a Windows Phone Runtime app (targetting Windows Phone 8.1) rather than a Windows Phone Silverlight app (for either 8.0 or 8.1). Chubosaurus' steps will create a Silverlight app.

You can confirm in the Solution Explorer, which will show the target for the project. To use System.Windows and MessageBox you will need a Windows Phone Silverlight app.

[image: Windows Phone Silverlight 8] [image: Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1]

If you have a Windows Phone 8.1 app you can use [Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx) instead 
[image]

```
Async Function ShowMyDialog() As Task(Of Boolean)
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Dim dialog As New Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Would you like to see the simple version?", "MessageDialog Example")
    dialog.Commands.Add(New Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Ok",
        Async Sub(command)
            result = True
            Dim okDialog As New Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("No caption, one button.")
            Await okDialog.ShowAsync()
        End Sub))
    dialog.Commands.Add(New Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Cancel"))
    dialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0
    dialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1
    Await dialog.ShowAsync()
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Many thanks to you. A had no Silverlight version, you are right! No with code example you provided I got working solution. Many thanks to you again!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your code.  It should work (I implemented it myself).  So it has to be some linking error / install error / or project creation error.

So lets fix, so lets try this:

- File -> New -> Project
- Select Template -> Visual Basic -> Store App -> windows Phone App -> Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight)
- Select 8.0 as the Target

---

It should generate you a blank app, then lets try and create a MessageBox on the Page Loaded Event

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Controls
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Controls
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Shell
Imports System.Windows

Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits PhoneApplicationPage

    ' Constructor
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait Or SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape

    End Sub

    Private Sub PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim result As MessageBoxResult = _
        MessageBox.Show("Would you like to see the simple version?", _
        "MessageBox Example", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel)

        If (result = MessageBoxResult.OK) Then
        ' Do whatever
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

---

If that doesn't work then we need to make sure that System.Windows is imported

- Right click on the Project -> Properties
- Click on References
- Make sure **System.Windows** has a checkmark

Comment: you are right: **System.Windows** was unchecked... I have check it, but no result, still same error. But when I try to make a new project as You asked - everything working fine. Mysticism...